# Is there more than one way of calculating F1-score

Tags: agreement-statistics

The reviewer of an article that I submitted to a journal commented that I never explicitly state how I calculate the F1-score. Is there more than one way to do it assuming that we are talking specifically about F1, not F2 or F-beta?

The mentioned article uses F1-score to measure inter-annotator agreement, so it does make sense to state precision and recall formulae, which I had done.

Comment: Even if there is only one formula, it's reasonable to request the formula to be stated explicitly for absolute clarity (especially considering the existence of F-beta...). At least mention that it is the harmonic mean of precision and recall not favouring one over the other.